# Summation and exponential problems

Tags: summation

Solving $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k(vt)^ke^{-vt}}{k!}$$ where v is a constant.  How is the answer equals vt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k(vt)^ke^{-vt}}{k!}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k(vt)^ke^{-vt}}{k!}$$
$$=vte^{-vt}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(vt)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}=vte^{-vt}\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(vt)^{j}}{j!}=$$
$$=vte^{-vt}e^{vt}=vt$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:$$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Comment: Your answer seems to be incorrect I DO NOT understand how you can work on variable $k$ outside the sign of summation. See my edit and my answer.

Comment: I've been looking at it since that It is not possible to work on variable k outside its sign of summation.